# Missing the "add tab group to favorites " option in IE8

Tags: bookmarks, internet-explorer-8

I have internet options selected for quick tabs and tab groups in settings, IE8 WIndows XP.

I can open a list of favorites from the menu using the blue arrow as a tab group.
I can then use the quick tabs button to show the groups open.

However, I do not have the "add tab group to favorites" option in the pull down menu for favorites at the Favorite Bar.

Is this a Vista feature only?

I just checked two of my Vista basic machines SP2, one also does NOT have the option.

The laptop DOES have the option.

Answer (score 0):

looks like is only a feature for windows vista and windows 7.

if I search **Tabbed browsing: frequently asked questions** in microsoft site.. I can just obtain links for windows 7 and windows vista.

[Link with research](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows7/search?q=tabbed+browsing&prd=)

> To save a group of tabs, click the
>   Favorites button, In Internet Explorer
>   8, click the arrow next to the Add to
>   Favorites button, and then click Add
>   Current Tabs to Favorites. In Internet
>   Explorer 7, click the Add to Favorites
>   button Picture of the Add to Favorites
>   , and then **click Add Tab Group to
>   Favorites**. Give the tab group a
>   name, and then click Add.

Comment: Just for Adding Add tab group to favorites. is an option of internet explorer 7.   this option is named "Add Current Tabs to Favorites" in IE8

Answer (score 0):

Two Answers.

1. Right Click in Favorite Bar
   Check menu Bar.
   Then Go to Favorites and choose "Add Current Tabs to Favorites".
2. Click the favourites button (star) and then the little arrow to the right of "Add to
   Favorites" at the top, and choose "Add Current Tabs to Favorites".